# Connect to Oracle from Azure Web Role - empty error message

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-web-roles, odp.net, oracle12c

I't trying to port an existing web application to run as an Azure Web Role. This application uses Oracle DB, which I've installed on an Azure VM using one of the new Images available there.

The problem arises when I try to connect from the web application to the database. I'm able to connect to the database from my developer PC (from Visual Studio using ODBC) and I'm able to telnet to the port, so no firewall issues.

I'm using this technique: http://www.splinter.com.au/using-the-new-odpnet-to-access-oracle-from-c/ which has been described several places online, including here on StackOverflow. The only difference is that I use Oracle 12 instead of 11, and use the appropriate 64 bit libraries.

The error I get, is not very descriptive:

```
[OracleException (0x80004005)]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable) +1199
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +53
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +4555
   NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection() +378
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare() +92
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper) +154
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory sessionFactory) +312
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners) +1934
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +292
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() +54

[FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

]
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() +111
   MAP.NHibernateHelper.CreateSessionFactory() in C:\ProjectSVN\FluentWims\DataAccessLayer\DataMapping\NHibernateHelper.vb:102
   MAP.NHibernateHelper.get_SessionFactory() in C:\ProjectSVN\FluentWims\DataAccessLayer\DataMapping\NHibernateHelper.vb:16
```

(Some lines deleted at the end as it contains some details I don't want to share publicly and I'm pretty sure they are irrelevant)

I've decompiled the managed code (OracleDataAccess.dll) and traced the problem to a call to this wrapped native call:

```
<DllImport("OraOps12.dll", EntryPoint:="OpsConOpen", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Shared Function Open(ByRef opsConCtx As IntPtr, ByRef opsErrCtx As IntPtr, ByRef pOpoConValCtx As OpoConValCtx, ByRef pOpoConRefCtx As OpoConRefCtx) As Integer
End Function
```

This returns -1, which isn't recognized as a known error code, and thus creates this exception which means next to nothing (at least not to me, even after googling like crazy ;)).

I have checked that if I remove OraOps12.dll, I get a different error message, and I've seen in ProcMon that the file is in fact found where I put it. I can find next to nothing about OraOps online, and what it means that this method returns -1.

Does anyone know what might be going on here, and what might be wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to look with a network monitor, at what is being sent to the oracle database, and I can't find any traffic - so OraOps seems to be called, but it doesn't get as far as to try to communicate with the database server.

The connection string I'm using, is copy/paste from the working connection in Visual Studio, so I assume it is correct. Even if it wasn't, I would expect a more descriptive error message back...

Comment: why do you insist on using a unsupported configuration?

Comment: Please elaborate. What is unsupported? The reason I'm doing this this way is that an Azure Web Role has limited access to modifying the environment. If there was a client which could be installed with a single exe or msi (without chatty UI), that would work well, but I haven't found anything like this.

Comment: copying around dll's and not installing the client software is for sure not supported. If you run into problems you will be on your own.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Oracle 11 with properly installed client (ODBC) using ODP.NET x64. It works for a while, then it suddenly stops working for some time, and then starts to work again fluctuating. Very peculiar.